# access violatoin when my program has two different QGLWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qglwidget

I have two different QGLWidgets(GLViwer and TextureViwer),and I add them into two QHboxLayout

```
glviewer = GLViewer::getInstance(); //QGLWidget singleton, display 3d model
texViewer = TextureViewer::getInstance();//display selected texture
ui.modelViewer->addWidget(glviewer); //add it to QHboxLayout
ui.textureViewer->addWidget(texViewer);
```

I render model with glDrawArrays() because it is fast.I have no problems when I only have GLViewer to display 3d model. but when I have two QGLWidget. it will cause a problem.

> access violation reading location 0x00000000...

I try to render model step by step(draw a triangle and another...), it works but without texture even though I call glTexCoord2f().

I have no idea why it happens. help me please:)

following is my init data code

```
glGenBuffers(3, this->buffers);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->buffers[VERTEXBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*9*objInfo->faces.size(), this->vertexs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->buffers[NORMALBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*9*objInfo->faces.size(), this->normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->buffers[TEXCOORDBUFFER]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*6*objInfo->faces.size(), this->texCoord, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

BUFFER_OFFSET(0) just like red book

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET(bytes) ((GLubytes*) NULL+(bytes))
```

GLViewer.h

```
class GLViewer : public QGLWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ~GLViewer();
    GLViewer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void drawModelWithTexArrayBuffer();
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
};
```

GLViewer.cpp

```
void GLViewer::initializeGL()
{
glewInit();
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void GLViewer::paintGL()
{

glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

if (isLoaded)
{
    timeCount.start();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glTranslated(modelCenter[0]+offsetX-(maxX+minX)/2,modelCenter[1]+ offsetY-(maxY+minY)/2 ,modelCenter[2]+zoomRate+minZ-3*(maxZ - minZ));
    glMultMatrixf(this->arcBall->Transform.M);
    glTranslated(-modelCenter[0], -modelCenter[1], -modelCenter[2]);
    if (this->modelWithtTex)
    {
        setLight(this->lightOn);
        if (showMesh)
        {
            drawModelLineArrayBuffer();
        }
        else
        {
            drawModelWithTexArrayBuffer();
            //drawModelWithTex();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        drawModelWithoutTexArrayBuffer();
    }
    int elapseTime = timeCount.elapsed();
}
} 

void GLViewer::resizeGL( int w, int h )
{
if (h == 0)
{
    h = 1;
}

    this->curWidth = w;
    this->curHeight = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1, 2000.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    this->arcBall->setBounds((GLfloat)w, (GLfloat)h);
}
void GLViewer::drawModelWithTexArrayBuffer()
{
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < objInfo->tex_filenames.size(); i++)
    {
        if (indRange[i].length == 0)
            continue;
        else
        {
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName[indRange[i].texId]);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, indRange[i].start, indRange[i].length);
        }
    }
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); 
}
```

TextureViewer.h

```
class TextureViewer : public QGLWidget
{
Q_OBJECT

public:

~TextureViewer();
TextureViewer(QWidget *parent = 0);
protected:
    void initializeGL();
    void paintGL();
    void resizeGL(int w, int h);
};
```

TextureViewer.cpp

```
void TextureViewer::initializeGL()
{
std::cout << "ddd" << std::endl;
glewInit();
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); 
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glCullFace(GL_BACK); 
glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
}

void TextureViewer::paintGL()
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslated(0, 0, -1);
glColor4f(1, 0, 1, 1);
glRectd(0,0,1,1);
}

void TextureViewer::resizeGL( int w, int h )
{
if (h == 0)
{
    h = 1;
}
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

gluPerspective(60.0, (GLfloat) w/(GLfloat) h, 1, 2000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each QGLWidget has its own OpenGL context and hence state, even if you create them as shared context, things like Vertex Array pointer locations are not covered by this sharing. Hence you must make the proper `gl…Pointer` calls just before calling `glDrawElements` or `glDrawArrays`. You don't do that properly.

Comment: I have post the code gl…Pointer.Could you help me to find out where is wrong.

Comment: @cloudending: Well, without seeing in which context (both OpenGL and QGLWidget) that code is running, it's hard to give any valuable advice. It would help if you posted your whole code. Please don't use a pastebin, just put it into your question.

Comment: @datanwolf the code is too long. so I post main part of it.`drawModelWithTexArrayBuffer();` is the main mathod to draw sence. and in TextureViewer. I just draw a rectangle.

Comment: @cloudending: What I'm looking for (in your code) is the way, i.e. how, where and which way you're allocating the VBOs. You already gave the code you use to create the VBOs. But the code snippets given do not show from where this code is being called. This is important. The exception your get and the way your program crashes suggests that you *try* to render from a VBO that actually isn't there; at least not in the OpenGL context active at the moment. So you either have to make the contexts share data, or recreate the VBOs for each context. Or reuse the context, but Qt doesn't support that.